# onError img doesn't work with 404 encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-router

I'm trying to catch error by onError (img). this works fine until a broken link (encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images) with a 404 code.

Here is my function. using antd.

```
<Avatar onError={() => false} className={styles['person-info__avatar']} src={author.image} size={42} />
```

Comment: what are you expecting the onError event to do? it is currently returning false. you can change the onError function to log the error event for more detail ```onError={(e) => console.log(e)}```

Comment: What is `Avatar`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This component is from antd library. Function onError doesn't except any arguments here: () => boolean. I've tried to use usual <img onError={(e) => console.log(e)} /> but it didn't work as well

Comment: antd Avatar: https://ant.design/components/avatar